# confusion in implementation of React's Flux

Tags: reactjs

I have been learning Flux in ReactJS. I have understood the the concept of flux that it divides app into four major parts that are Action, Dispatcher, Store, and View. Action is responsible for generating actions and sending them to dispatcher. Dispatcher dispatches those actions to all the stores registered with it. Store gets itself registered with Dispatcher to listen for dispatched events. And View listens to changes occurring in Store and updates its (View's) state according to those changes.

But I am unable to implement this technique exactly using Flux's/React's syntax. I have seen many examples but I have confused after seeing different types of flux's implementations.

Therefore, can someone please write a simple code that shows the proper implementation of flux and its parts i.e. Action, Dispatcher, Store, and View. And it should also shows clearly the way of communication between these parts.

Comment: Have you looked at Facebook's implementation of Flux? It doesn't get much more "proper" than that. https://github.com/facebook/flux

Comment: This youtube playlist gives you a very basic implementation of flux along with the code. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b